# Events on Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, triggers

I am new to Backbone and am wondering something.

I've seen some tutorial where the user uses this code to explain an event.

```
var ImageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ initialize: function(){
this.on('change',this.someChange,this); //when some property in this object has changed, run this.someChange() function },

defaults : { title : 'untitled', 
description : 'no description available',
owner : 'anonymous',
date : 'no date supplied' },

someChange: function(model,options){ alert(‘something has changed’); 
}
}); 
var photo = new ImageModel({title:’awesome image’}); //create new instance

photo.set(‘title’,’really awesome indeed’); //change the title attribute, this will trigger ‘change’ event

photo.set({title:’well i agree’},{agree: ‘yep’}); //alternative way to change model attribute with optional option passed, this will also trigger change event. </p>
```

And In some other examples I've seen people usings triggers to activate the event.

Eg

```
`var object = {};
_.extend(object, Backbone.Events); object.on("alert", function(msg) { 
 alert("Triggered " + msg); }); 
 object.trigger("alert", "an event");
```

My questions is how do the first example use the event '**change**' when it doesn't get trigged in anyway. It doesn't use '**change**' anywhere in the code. I know that it uses the function **someChange** but how does it now to "activate" when the event isn't trigged or "used" in the code.

If you're not understanding the question I am sorry. Not sure how to explain the problem.

Comment: changes to Backbone model attributes automatically fire change events - the event typically takes the form of change:attribute where attribute is the actual property name of the attribute in question

Comment: Ah okey. but the name 'change' for event name doesn't matter? Let's say for example I would change **'change'** to **'event'** then I would use event:title if I wanted something to happend on the change of my title attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to spend a little time reading the Backbone documentation (shouldn't take you more than 1 hour). There is a list of predefined events you will be using *a lot* when writing Backbone applications: "change", "reset", and so on.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Regarding your particular example, `Backbone.Events` is the component used inside Backbone to provide any object/class with event emitting functionality. `Backbone.Model` of course *includes* `Backbone.Events`.

Your first snippet shows how to listen to a Backbone.Model `change` event to do something, while the second mixes the `Backbone.Events` into a JS object to be able to trigger from it.

That's the beauty of Backbone, the same methods (`on`, `off`, `listenTo`) are used in Models, Views, Collections, because they all inherit Backbone.Events. Once you grasp it, it's all rock and roll. :)